# Как поставить фото профиля Телеграма в полном разрешении, не сжатое? Я видела у одного человека стоит

Tags: telegram

не 640 на 640, а 1280 на 1280.

Comment: А дата аватарки у этого человека какая? Скорее всего это было много лет назад и такую возможность давно убрали

Comment: @andreymal 2016-й год